# Should I get BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS also when disconnecting from a device?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am working with custom devices and I am struggling to manage the Bluetooth LE correctly.

My only concern is not getting 0 (`BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS`) when I read the `status` value  along with value 2 on `newState` variable (what means `BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED`) at method `onConnectionStateChange`. Instead, I get an 8, what can't be tracked in the `BluetoothGatt` nor `BluetoothProfile` classes.

All connection works fine, I read and write values perfectly.

**(1)** Is this supposed to be like that? Why do I read an eight?

I have seen many `status` values at my `onConnectionStateChange` method: 8, 19, 133 etc.

**(2)** Where can I check this values?

Thanks in advance

---

**EDIT**: There are many values in the *api.h* file, we were looking in the wrong place.

`8: 0x08 = GATT CONN TIMEOUT
19: 0x13 = GATT CONN TERMINATE PEER USER 
133: 0x85 = GATT_ERROR`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is no.

I wasn't getting `BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS` because the connection was closed by the other end. If `gatt.disconnect()` is executed I read `status = BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS`.

Answer (score 1):

The int error codes need to be converted to HEX and mapped to the values in the following file:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/bluetooth/bluedroid/+/android-5.1.1_r13/stack/include/gatt_api.h

In the cases you mentioned:

```
8 = GATT_INSUF_AUTHORIZATION
19 = GATT_RSP_WRITE 
133 = GATT_ERROR
```

Comment: Unfortunately the names are not meaningful, however, the source looks nice. Any idea on question **(1)**: Is this supposed to be like that? Why do I read an eight?

Comment: It looks like some kind of authentication problem. Maybe before you connect to the BLE device you need to pair with it... it depends on the device's requirements.

Comment: When I take the battery of the device off while connected it still reads ``status`` as 8, so I guess it's not related to any authentication. Any other ideas ?